# Dynamic bounds change does not give any effect in 'react-leaflet'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, fitbounds

I encountered the problem while trying to use the `react-leaflet`'s `bounds` property.
My use case is that my application has some initial bounds defined in the state (let's say, fallback bounds), and those bounds are passed during the first render of component. The app architecture requires me to send request for the new bounds to set within the component, and here comes the problem.

On the example below (where I've simulated AJAX request using `setTimeout`) we can notice that the new bounds which are coming from request after timeout are not set at all, and I'm not quite sure why it's happening.

I suspect that is something with animation, because when increased timeout delay, the problem does not occur, and the second bounds are set correctly.

My setup:

```
"react": "17.0.0"
"leaflet": "1.6.0"
"react-leaflet": "2.7.0"
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Map, ZoomControl, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";

import "./styles.css";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

export default function App() {
  const [bounds, setBounds] = useState([
    [75, -25],
    [30, 45]
  ]);

  setTimeout(() => {
    setBounds([
      [59.569068610511465, 10.387057922780514],
      [59.565111563593824, 10.397184267640114]
    ]);
  }, 200);

  return (
    <Map
      bounds={bounds}
      maxBounds={bounds}
      zoomControl={false}
      style={{
        height: 400,
        width: 400
      }}
    >
      <TileLayer
        url="//{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}"
        maxZoom={21}
        minZoom={4}
        minZoomIsDrawing={18}
        subdomains={["mt0", "mt1", "mt2", "mt3"]}
      />
      <ZoomControl />
    </Map>
  );
}
```

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-silence-vnt23

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an effect to get the map instance to change the map bounds.

Check [here](https://react-leaflet.js.org/legacy/docs/en/components) for more info.

```
const mapRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const map = mapRef.current?.leafletElement;
    map.fitBounds([
      [59.569068610511465, 10.387057922780514],
      [59.565111563593824, 10.397184267640114]
    ]);
  }, []);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-bounds-change-does-not-give-any-effect-in-react-leaflet-9jh83)

Comment: I'm aware of that I could use the map reference and handle it under the hood, but shouldn't 'bounds' property be a dynamic one? How suppose I need to change a global bounds then? I think that the Leaflet's map will change twice.
Anyway, I see the demo is not working at all.

Comment: You are right. It should work based on the documentation. On version 3 it is mentioned that `Except for its children, MapContainer props are immutable` [link](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map). I wonder if it applies the same on verson 2.x. By the way the demo should work. It shows Scandinavia zoomed out in your example but on the demo the same area zoomed in.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Now the demo looks good to me. Well... I see, for now there is no other way to use it dynamically through the props.

Answer (score -2):

You can pass one of the value of the new bounds as a key on your MapContainer.
React will consider that your map has changed and will rerendered it (be careful the component's state will be also reset).

https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useState#resetting-state-with-a-key

```
<Map key={bounds[0][0]}>
```

You can also use the useMap hook, there is a topic about it:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66839063/how-to-use-bounds-with-dynamic-markers-in-react-leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66839063/how-to-use-bounds-with-dynamic-markers-in-react-leaflet?rq=1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.